# How do I sort dates into months and their respective numbers into positives and negatives separately?

Tags: sql, group-by, phpmyadmin, sum, pivot

I've got a simple table that has a column called Date and it stores '2015-01-15' data as an example, it ranges in '####-##-##' and there's multiple of the same dates, but following it is a number called Amount with values 0, -## and ##. 
How would I go through to making it sum up all the negative and positives separately per month?

Example data

```
[ Amount | Date      ]
[ 0      | 2015-01-01]
[ -15    | 2015-01-09]
[ 566    | 2015-01-15]
[ 6      | 2015-01-25]
[ -2     | 2015-02-01]
[ -15    | 2015-02-09]
[ 10     | 2015-02-15]
[ 6      | 2015-02-25]
```

So the new data would be in

```
[ Positives | Negatives | Date   ]
[ 572       | -15       | 2015-01]
[ 16        | -17       | 2015-02]
```

And so on

Comment: Tag your question with the database you are using.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do conditional aggregation; `least()` and `greatest()` come handy to shorten the query.

Assuming that you are running MySQL, like the `phpmyadmin` tag suggest:

```
select
    sum(greatest(amount, 0)) positives,
    sum(least(amount, 0)) negatives,
    date_format(date, '%Y-%m') mon
from mytable
group by date_format(date, '%Y-%m')
```

Answer (score 0):

Use conditional aggregation:

```
select year(date), month(date),
       sum(case when amount > 0 then amount end) as positives,
       sum(case when amount < 0 then amount end) as negatives
from t
group by year(date), month(date);
```

Date functions vary significantly between databases.  Although not standard, most support `year()` and `day()`.  However, you might need different functions for your database.